# Unexpected behaviour in URI.join

Tags: ruby

`URI::join` removes everything after a `/` character in its arguments unless there is a matching `/`. For instance:

```
URI::join("http://www.example.com/prefix", "some_path").to_s
#=> "http://www.example.com/some_path"

URI::join("http://www.example.com/prefix/", "some_path").to_s
#=> "http://www.example.com/prefix/some_path"
```

What's the reason behind it, and how are we supposed to handle this without relying on tools that are not meant to be used in that scenario (such as `File.join`)? I need to use values of either type for base url.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: What ruby version?

Comment: I've reproduced it with 2.2.0p0, 2.1.5p273, 1.9.3-p392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected and [documented behavior](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-join) (albeit somewhat hidden in the *Usage* section):

> ```
> p URI.join('http://example.com', '/foo', '/bar')
> # => #<URI::HTTP:0x01aaf0b0 URL:http://example.com/bar>
>
> p URI.join('http://example.com', '/foo', 'bar')
> # => #<URI::HTTP:0x801a92af0 URL:http://example.com/bar>
>
> p URI.join('http://example.com', '/foo/', 'bar')
> # => #<URI::HTTP:0x80135a3a0 URL:http://example.com/foo/bar>
> ```

You can handle it by making sure that your path fragments are always complete path fragments with slashes on both sides.

Comment: thanks, nice that answers it. Though, expected, hmmm. documented, hmmm. surprising, yes.

Comment: It still makes no sense to me :S

Comment: "You can handle it by making sure that your path fragments are always complete path fragments with slashes on both sides." is the key. The trailing `/` of a path segment tells us that segment is a directory if we're dealing with a path to a file, which a URL can point to. It doesn't *have* to point to a file, but it helps to think of the path that way. A segment of a path that doesn't end with `/` would traditionally be a file so the first two examples replace the `/foo` file with the `/bar` file. The third adds the `bar` file to the `/foo/` directory.